# jQuery page redirect after submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form like this

```
<form id="add-to-cart" name="my-form" action="http://www.example.com" method="post">
  <div class="row flat">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
    <button type="submit"  value="submit" data-value="2" data-name="id">Buy Now</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

To Save the form I have used jQuery. So for now my code looks like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('button').click(function(){
        var Value = jQuery(this).attr('data-value');
        jQuery('[name="id"]').val(Value);
        jQuery('#add-to-cart').submit();
        window.location = "http://www.page-2.com";
        });
    });
  </script>
```

But here after submit the form is not redirecting to another page(http://www.page-2.com).
  So can someone kindly tell me how to do redirect the form after submit the form?

**Update**
Sorry here I can't use ajax. I want to submit the form in simple.

Comment: from submit will do redirect to the post page

Comment: You can make the redirection happen from the page specified in the `action` attribute of the form

Comment: Please let me know whether my solution worked or not. So, that I can help you in another possible way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use ajax, the form will be submitted, and the browser redirected to the action url of the form. The only way to do a redirection after the submit, is to do it in the handler of the action form. You could however add a parameter with the URL you want to redirect to.

The only advantage of that solution over a solution involving ajax is that no javascript is required. It would work whether javascrit is enabled or not.

Comment: The main part would be on the server side. What language are you using on the server side?

Comment: I am using php. But I want to submit the form through jQuery and after submit the form I just want to redirect the page. Sorry but I can't change the server files.

Comment: In that case, your only option is to use ajax

Comment: without ajax is it not possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54260/discussion-between-newuser-and-maurice-perry).

Comment: Wait a minute. There is another solution: you could use an iframe as the target of your form

Answer (score 7):

You can handle this in your action, you calling `onSubmit()` from server code redirect it to the page you want.

Or you need to use ajax post() calls which give you onSuccess and onFailure events on call complete. Something like this:

```
$('#add-to-cart').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
           window.location.href = "http://www.page-2.com";
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

Comment: sorry here I can't use ajax.I have to submit the form using submit function

Comment: then go with option 1, handle it in action you calling onsubmit

Comment: @NewUser if you don't use ajax for submission, you have to redirect to **www.page-2.com** from the php page that handles the form with the following php code: `<?php header("Location: http://www.page-2.com");?>`  **Note:** without ajax you can't come back to the pervious page, so the `window.location.href = "http://www.page-2.com";`will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

**html:**

```
                    <form action="javascript:searchItem();">
                        <div class="searchbox">
                            <div class="search-inner">
                                <div class="item-input">
                                    <input type="text" id="itemName" placeholder="Search Product" required/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-after">
                                    <input type="submit" value="" class="button-search"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function searchItem() {

    $.ajax({
        url: urlDomain + "pricelist/?itemName=" + $("#itemName").val(),
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        success: function(data) {
            // do your work on success and then,
            location.href = "path/to/next/Page/To/Display.html";
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

I wrote above code for getting values from server, but you can change jQuery "Type" parameter to "POST" and add "data" parameter with its values you want to be sent to server.

Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Disable the **form** submission using **onsubmit="return false;"**

**html**

```
<form id="add-to-cart" name="my-form" action="http://www.example.com" method="post">
```

**js**

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('button').click(function(){
             var form = $(this).parents('form');

             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: $(this).attr('action'),
                 data: form.serialize(),
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(response) {
                      window.location.href = "http://www.page-2.com";
                 }
             });
             return false;
           });
      });
</script>
```

keep the **action** attribute value as a fallback, so you'll be sure that your form will work correctly even if **javascript** is enabled or not on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but I found a different way to redirect after submitting a form.

First of all, to reiterate the basics of the `<form>` tag since the OP was literally a NewUser, submitting a form has redirecting built into it.  If you change your original html from:

```
<form id="add-to-cart" name="my-form" action="http://www.example.com" method="post">
```

to:

```
<form id="add-to-cart" name="my-form" action="http://www.page-2.com" method="post">
```

then clicking on your submit `<button>` will automatically redirect you.

However, maybe NewUser wants submitting the form to always stay on www.example.com and only sometimes redirect to www.page-2.com, once the submission is complete?  I ran into this exact scenario at work today.

In my case, we had a form that consisted of data in a table.  Users could make changes to the data and then click the submit button (called "Save") to save the changes in the database.  The action of `<form>` just refreshed the form/table page because we wanted users to stay on that page.

We also had a link on that page that would take you to another page, but I had to make sure that it autosaved all the data before redirecting.  So I made the link submit the form, and then redirect.  This was accomplished with jQuery, and without Ajax.  Here it is, adapted to NewUser's code:

(`<form>` is unchanged, action="http://www.example.com")

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // The link has class="linky-link" for easy selecting and href="http://www.page-2.com".  I did not use an id because I had multiple nearly identical links on the same page.
  $(".linky-link").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // Don't redirect yet!
    var $form = $("#add-to-cart");  // $form instead of form because it's shorthand for a jQuery selector - not strictly necessary, but helpful
    $form.append("<input type='hidden' name='link_redirect' value='" + this.href + "'>");  // This is added to the end of the form and triggers the redirect after the saving is done
    $form.submit(); // Submitting the form saves the data, and then redirects
    });
});
</script>
```

(Note: be sure this bit of JavaScript is located at the very bottom of the php file, once everything else is loaded)