# php jquery onclick submit redirect to another page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I'm trying to make this work but there something wrong:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<script>location='https://google.com'</script>";
exit();
}
?>

<html>
<head>

<script>
    function onSubmit() {
        document.getElementById('menu_post').value = 'main';
        document.forms['MenuForm'].submit();
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>

<a onclick="onSubmit();return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>

<form name="MenuForm" method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="menu_post" name="menu_post" value="" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried this one [[php on submit redirect to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271713/php-on-submit-redirect-to-another-page])

But still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery page redirect after submit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822566/jquery-page-redirect-after-submit-the-form)

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the context for this because there's much better ways of achieving what you're doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<script>window.location.href='https://google.com'</script>";
    exit();
}
```

### Edit

You've actually nothing being posted as 'submit'.

```
if(isset($_POST['menu_post'])){
    echo "<script>window.location.href='https://google.com'</script>";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: first one didn't work, the edit one automatically redirects without user action. :(

Comment: oh! the second one actually works! great! thanks so much!

Comment: thats no problem